# GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses cause query to be slow

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

I have a following query which executes for a very long time. Both article_category and article tables have approximately 250k rows. I tried some multiple-column indexes but nothing what would speed up the query. Current EXPLAIN is like this (that status index currently used consists of article.status and article.published and optimizer currently decided to use it).

Can you give me some advice which index to create to speed up this query?

1 SIMPLE    a   ref PRIMARY,status,published    status  1   const   109338  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

1 SIMPLE    ac  ref PRIMARY,fk_article_category_category_id_category_id PRIMARY 4   e15.a.id    1   Using where

1   SIMPLE  c   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   e15.ac.category_id  1

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `a`.`id`,`a`.`title`,`a`.`perex`,`a`.`published`,`a`.`updated`,`a`.`article_type_id`,`a`.`tag`   ,`ac`.`category_id`,`c`.`name`,`a`.`top_hp`,`ac`.`top_category`,`a`.`is_pr`,`a`.`seo_title`,`c`.`id_domain` 
FROM `article` `a`  
JOIN `article_category` `ac` ON `ac`.`article_id` = `a`.`id` 
JOIN `category` `c` ON `ac`.`category_id`=`c`.`id` 
WHERE `ac`.`category_id` IN (109,118,38,39,40,62,63,119,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,121,122) 
AND `a`.`status`='published' AND a.published < "2014-02-03 22:45:00"
GROUP BY `a`.`id` 
ORDER BY `a`.`published` DESC 
LIMIT 0,8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Index were not used because of the different ORDER BY a GROUP BY clauses.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

You should limit your results before joining them, for example like this (untested!):

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `a`.`id`,`a`.`title`,`a`.`perex`,`a`.`published`,`a`.`updated`,`a`.`article_type_id`,`a`.`tag`   ,`ac`.`category_id`,`c`.`name`,`a`.`top_hp`,`ac`.`top_category`,`a`.`is_pr`,`a`.`seo_title`,`c`.`id_domain` 
FROM 
(
SELECT `id` FROM `category` WHERE `id` IN (109,118,38,39,40,62,63,119,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,121,122) 
) `c` JOIN `article` `a`  
JOIN `article_category` `ac` ON `ac`.`article_id` = `a`.`id` 
JOIN ON `ac`.`category_id`=`c`.`id` 
WHERE `a`.`status`='published' AND a.published < "2014-02-03 22:45:00"
GROUP BY `a`.`id` 
ORDER BY `a`.`published` DESC 
LIMIT 0,8
```

Comment: This performs (280 s)even worse (when fixed), but thanks for a try :-)

Comment: Maybe you can redesign the query, that the " where 'a'.... " clause is also performed before joining